# How did Evelyn cook the food from the floor?

Tags: a-quiet-place

In the science-fiction movie *A Quiet Place* (2018), Evelyn pulls out the tray with cooked fish from the floor.

[image: smoke coming out of a trap in wooden floor planks, a hand raising some cooked food]

How did she cook the food from the floor?

Comment: I haven't seen it, but it looks like she's probably smoking the fish in some kind of built-in smoker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The film script indicates that she's made a rudimentary [earth  oven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_oven) using rocks that she's heated in her fire and then buried underground (or possibly that are part of the cabin's [underfloor heating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underfloor_heating)).

> WIDER NOW, we see EVELYN on her hands and knees just behind the living room set up in an open, very make-shift kitchen.One wall of shelves cluttered with stacks of paper plates, bowls and cups. Another wall is a workbench acting as a counter top and a mid 70’s refrigerator.
>
> EVELYN extracts from the dirt a long wooden box. Beneath it... red hot rocks let off a combination of steam and smoke.
>
> EVELYN brings the box to the counter top and carefully lifts the lid to reveal... a perfectly cooked fish with lemon and rosemary and garlic scattered all around.